# Php preg_match code to split string ending with numbers

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7

considers a string that is based on the following :
1. can contain any alphanumeric characters
2. the string ends with number(s)

Now by using `preg_match($expression, $subject, $parts)` I want to split the string in such a manner that the ending numbers and the rest of the string is stored in the **$parts** array separately.

for example: kim2bn88 should result in two parts: kim2bn and 88

But I am not able to figure out the regex. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a regex like as follows:

```
/^(\w+)(\d+)$/
```

Assuming you always have non-digits before the final digits.

This gives you two capture groups.  The first are word characters (alphanumeric + _) at the start of the string.  The second are digits at the end of the string.

Comment: thanks! this worked for me. Sorry for the late expression of gratitude though :p

Answer (score 1):

The regexp your are searching for must use the end boundary “$”.

```
/(\d+)$/
```

If you want to avoid a split, next to this search, try this double “group and extract”:

```
/((\d)+)$/
```

$parts will contain "88", "8", "8". The first item of the array will be the whole numerical subset, then one item per digit.